# How to embed a image using the ColdBox MailService plugin

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I am using the ColdBox MailService plugin to send emails. I am not sure how to include/embed an image in my email.

I tried the `<cfmailparm>` tag but this will not work because it is not enclosed in a `<cfmail>` tag.

```
<img src="cid:headerImage" width="350" height="263" alt="" /><br />
 <cfmailparam file="/#application.rootDirectory#/includes/img/generic_header_lg.gif"
              contentid="headerImage"
              disposition="inline"/>
```

Is there another option I can try with the MailService plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The mail service has methods to add Params. Have you looked at the API

Comment: please provide specific answer

Answer (score 0):

Extrapolating from the [docs](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Plugins%3aMailService.cfm), try `addMailParam(disposition='inline')`

Example

```
local.Email.addMailParam(disposition="inline"
    ,file="/#application.rootDirectory#/includes/img/generic_header_lg.gif"
    ,contentid="headerImage");
```